# The iframe close in Firefox and IE7 but it doesn't close in Chrome

Tags: javascript

Any suggestion to close Thickbox Iframe from Chrome?
the code I use:

```
onClick="parent.eval('tb_remove()')"
```

Comment: Perhaps a dirty fix, but can't you just set the innerHtml of the container element to ""?

Comment: Are you running this on a local machine?

Comment: Local yes and its work in all browsers expt Chrome

Comment: OMG.. its work fine when I publish it ... thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Chrome doesn't allow cross-frame access when running pages locally. It's a part of their security policy.

You need to open Chrome with `--allow-file-access-from-files` argument, then drag and drop the main file on Chrome window. Also please use the code T.J. Crowder has suggested, using `eval()` here is totally unnecessary.

I've added the argument to the Chrome-icon's running path on my desktop, though it vanishes quite often.

Answer (score 0):

This should do it:

```
parent.tb_remove();
```

...provided of course the `iframe` and the containing document are from the [same origin](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy). (If they aren't, they can't talk at all.)

There's no reason to use `eval` here (or *almost* anywhere else). Your code expects `eval` to be a property of the `window` object, and expects `tb_remove` to be a global function. Global functions are properties of the `window` object, so you can (and should) just call it directly.